# How to use Audio File Services to get the raw data of an audio file?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I'm trying to use the Audio File Services from the AudioToolBox framework to get the raw data from a wav file. Specifically, I'm using AudioFileReadBytes() call to get the bytes. Here is the relevant code I have:

```
NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSString stringWithCString:argv[1]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                           stringByExpandingTildeInPath];          
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];               

AudioFileID audioFile;                                               
OSStatus theErr = noErr;
UInt64 fileDataSize = 0;
AudioStreamBasicDescription theFileFormat;
UInt32 thePropertySize = sizeof(theFileFormat);
theErr = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)audioURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &audioFile); 

thePropertySize = sizeof(fileDataSize);
theErr = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &thePropertySize, &fileDataSize);

//Read data into buffer
UInt32 dataSize = fileDataSize;
void* theData = malloc(dataSize);
if (theData) {
    AudioFileReadBytes(audioFile, false, 0, &dataSize, theData);
            // create an NSData object to hold the buffer data
    NSData* nsdata = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:theData length:dataSize]; //?
}
```

Now the question is: after I create the NSData object (nsdata), how do I get the numbered values from it (like if I do 'wavread' in Matlab it will give me an array of floats) so that I can manipulate the values(e.g. to pass through some filter)?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you need the NSData object at all.

Using AudioFileGetProperty with kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, you should be able to determine the type of audio data (e.g. array of floats) etc, and therefore how to interpret "theData".

Comment: Hi JonoB, thanks for your reply. It's not necessary to use NSData. I just need to get the array of floats. Could you show me some example of using kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat? Some line of codes will be very helpful.

Comment: e.g. (without having actually compiled/tested the following, but it should give you the idea): 
`AudioStreamBasicDescription theFileFormat;
AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyClientDataFormat, &thePropertySize, &audioFile); 
// AudioFileReadBytes as you are already doing now  
... ;
 
if (theFileFormat.mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat) 
{ 
    // Data is in float format. 
    float* dataAsFloat = (float*)theData; 
    // You can now access you data as floats, e.g. dataAsFloat[0]. 
}`