# How do you get the sampling rate of an AudioFileID?

Tags: ios, wav, sampling, rate

It is easy in iOS to get the number of bytes in a loaded .wav file:

```
UInt64 dataSize = 0;  // dataSize
UInt32 ps = sizeof(UInt64); // property size
if( AudioFileGetProperty(fileId, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &ps, &dataSize) )
  puts( "error retriving data chunk size" );
return dataSize ;
```

But [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html) I cannot seem to find any information on how to determine the sampling rate of a PCM wave file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer using [AudioStreamBasicDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101150/how-to-use-audio-file-services-to-get-the-raw-data-of-an-audio-file).  All you have to do is:

```
UInt32 getAudioDataSamplingRate( AudioFileID fileId )
{
  AudioStreamBasicDescription bsd;
  UInt32 ps = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription) ;
  if( AudioFileGetProperty(fileId, 
      kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &ps, &bsd) )
    puts( "error retriving af basic description" );
  return bsd.mSampleRate ;
}
```